# How to find faculty hiring ads for US, Canada and Europe

Tags: faculty-application

I'm planning to apply to faculty (assistant professor) jobs. The process looks similar to graduate school applications. But I was wondering, are there easier ways to find position openings instead of going to each school's website one by one?

And a summary of the comments:

1. Talk to Advisors
2. Particular field-specific mailing list
3. Websites

Comment: Do you mean worldwide, or US, Canada, and Europe?

Comment: No site will list all jobs worldwide.  Only jobs that advertise on that site.  That said, there's the Chronicle for Higher Education for the US, and you may have more options if you specify a discipline (e.g., mathjobs for math jobs.)

Comment: I don't believe there is a single site. Where you can find job ads will depend on the field, country, and phase of the moon.

Comment: I just updated the question thanks

Comment: I've voting to reopen the question because it seeks ways of finding job applications in general, rather than specific websites.

Comment: In my field, the go-to resource would be a particular field-specific mailing list. It's also helpful to be on Twitter and follow researchers in the relevant areas.

Comment: @Dr_Hope Do you have an advisor or mentor? I would recommend asking them not only this, but also advice on how to conduct your job search and how to prepare your job materials. A lot of it will be specific to your research area and your situation. Good luck.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I still think the question may be too broad to have good answers.  I would recommend specifying the type of job and picking a single geographic region.

Comment: @Kimball Counterexample I already gave in a comment: "In my field, the go-to resource would be a particular field-specific mailing list. It's also helpful to be on Twitter and follow researchers in the relevant areas.". This would allow OP to search for such mailing lists in their field and to check out Twitter. Also doesn't require to narrow down to a particular type of (faculty) job or region.

Comment: @Thomas Not totally true: some countries (e.g. France) have a centralized website which lists all the assistant professor / professor positions each year.